# Translate Lua table to C++

Tags: c++, lua

I have a Lua table like this:

```
t_big={
{open,high,low,close, sd, far_sd},
{open,high,low,close, sd, far_sd},
{open,high,low,close, sd, far_sd},
{open,high,low,close, sd, far_sd},
}--many lines like these. Open, high, low, close, sd, far_sd are different numbers.
```

I translate this code to C++. Help me to find similar container (dictionary). It must support VERY high speed, because I will learn this data using brute force. Lua script makes its job for 1 week. I study C++ to do this job faster.
Lua brute force circle looks like:

```
for sd=start_sd,end_sd,1 do 
 for far_sd=start_far_sd,end_far_sd,0.25 do 
 ..... work with container, check sd and far_sd parameters. Seeking best result.
 end 
end
```

Comment: FWIW, it's not the language that's fast, it's how you use it.  You can make some pretty slow using C++ as well.  Brute force is normally the worst approach so it's going to be slow no matter what language you chose.  That said, you really need to add more detail on how you wan to access this information so we can help you to pick an appropriate container.

Comment: added answer to post

Comment: Agreeing with @NathanOliver, "parallel arrays" is a technique that applies to both languages. (In Lua, they would be tables with sequences. The potential advantage in Lua would be avoiding a table per "row".)

Comment: @Kosmonavt: "*Help me to find similar container (dictionary)*" Nothing you're doing in that code constitutes a "dictionary"; all of those tables, including the containing one, are just arrays.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually not really clear what are you asking. From available information I came up with few ideas:

1. Classic arrays or `std::array`. General con is that their size is defined in compile time (source files), which may be bad idea overall. Store your entries as `struct` for easier field naming.
2. `std::vector`. Just as previous one, but it's runtime-sized. Store entries same way.
3. From your "brute force" example it's pretty clear that you're doing it wrong way. Look at any kind of SQL database: SQLite is probably best choice at the moment. It will require some learning, but should be pretty easy overall. If your table is hardcoded (I'm pretty sure it's not, but who knows), you can find SQLite bindings for lua and export it easily. If it's not, you always can create in-memory database which is ultra fast (don't forget about indexing table anyways!). To make things much easier, you'll likely want to use some wrapper for SQLite, like https://github.com/SqliteModernCpp/sqlite_modern_cpp.

If language itself is not important (you came to C++ only for speed), consider using SQLite bindings for lua, it should be easier for you and still much faster than bruteforcing table like you do now.